# Find TreeViewItem to drop data

Tags: c#, xaml, treeview, drag-and-drop

I want to drag data from a ListView and drop it in a TreeView(the draging works fine). I use DataBinding and ItemTemplate to fill the TreeView.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" Name="tvGroups" AllowDrop="True"
          Drop="tvDrop" DragOver="tvDragOver">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Participants}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <Button Tag="{Binding .}" Click="Button_Click_2">
                    <Image Source="Resources/cross.png" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Alias}" />
                        <Button Tag="{Binding .}" Name="btnDeleteParticipants" Click="btnParticipants_Click" >
                            <Image Source="Resources/cross.png" />
                        </Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

---

```
private void tvDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Effects == DragDropEffects.Copy &&
        e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(Participant)))
    {
        Participant data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Participant)) as Participant;
    }
}
```

A `Participant` is dragged from the ListView to the TreeView. Now I need to find the `Group`. Any ideas where to get the right `Group` from the TreeView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply set the Drop="tvDrop" and DragOver="tvDragOver" on the StackPanel in the HierarchicalDataTemplate's ItemTemplate.

This way
1) You don't have any risk of getting an event when something is dropped out of a group
2) You can safely cast the Sender to a FrameworkElement and get the DataContext and cast it to your class.

You can also set a different handler on the treeview itself if you need to support dragging out of the groups.

Comment: I bound the group to the StackPanel.Tag and that just works fine. Thanks a lot.